# How to read detected NFC tag (NDEF content) details in android?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I want to read NDEF content contained within a detected NFC tag (i.e., Tag id, Tag Size, Tag Type, Is tag Writable, Target Type, and message types).

Comment: Thanks for ur comment... upto now i get Tag id & Target type by 
Tag myTag = (Tag) nfcintent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
String tagTechlist[]= myTag.getTechList();
byte[] tagID=myTag.getId();

Now i want to get, the text in that tag, Tag size, Tag type and Is writable or not...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about tags with NDEF content? In that case, you can do:

```
Tag myTag = (Tag) nfcintent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

// get NDEF tag details
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(myTag);
int size = ndefTag.getMaxSize();         // tag size
boolean writable = ndefTag.isWritable(); // is tag writable?
String type = ndefTag.getType();         // tag type

// get NDEF message details
NdefMessage ndefMesg = ndefTag.getCachedNdefMessage();
NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMesg.getRecords();
int len = ndefRecords.length;
String[] recTypes = new String[len];     // will contain the NDEF record types
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  recTypes[i] = new String(ndefRecords[i].getType());
}
```

Comment: You might also want to check out [nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) for further details, or alternatively a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) I wrote for creating NDEF messages.

Comment: And one more thing, i want to read the data message in the Ndef tag... please very urgent... help me...

Comment: `byte[] mesg = ndefRecords[i].getPayload()`, see also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html

Comment: And if you want more details of the NdefRecords, try http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/ for a higher-level record representation