# How can i read NFC tag in android?

Tags: android, nfc

Hi i am developing an android application using NFC feature. Here i tried to read NFC Mifare nfc tag. I used NFCDemo which is available with android api.But i did not get success to read data through my application. In that demo that is always reading fake tags and giving fake result only.

I have a confusion about the manifest file intent filters. In my demo application is like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.nfc"
>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <activity android:name=".simulator.FakeTagsActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name="TagViewer"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

And the application is always starting with FakeTagsActivity activity any showing list of fake tags.When we click on any one of the fake tags it will redirect to TagViewer activity with fake data not the real tag data. 
I have confusion too in TagViewer activity also that is resolveIntent(Intent intent) is handling always

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {}
```

but i am not understanding whats the wrong with this. 
Please advice me am i need to modify the api demo to read real tag data. Or advice me is there any other way to read the nfc tag.

I already tried [This Sample](http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.in/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html)
but not help full for me.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", are you trying on a real device? Are you sure that device has NFC hardware support in it?

Comment: Yes i tried on Samsung Verizon 4g device. It has NFC capability.

Comment: The NFCDemo app is really outdated, I wouldn't use it to build off of. But, lets try to figure out the problem first. You are saying that when you click on one of the fake tags it goes to TagView activity with the fake data. That is expected. At what point do you actually scan your tag? I didn't catch in your question when you did that.

Comment: Thanks for your response @David Wasser,@ robertly. The problem is i gave the low priority in my intent filter.I modified that now the app working fine to detect the nfc tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out solution for my question. There we need to update the intent filter of TagViewer activity like

```
 <activity android:name="TagViewer"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Then I modified my if condition of TagViewer class like

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {}
```

It will working fine now. The main problem is priorites of TAG detection those are
priority 1 : NDEF_DISCOVERED
priority 2 : TECH_DISCOVERED
priority 3 : TAG_DISCOVERED

I gave the priority 1 for my application intent filter then the android system always starting my activity when the tag detected.

Comment: An NDEF_DISCOVERED intent will only be sent by Android if the discovered NFC tag contains an NDEF message. If it does not, only a TECH_DISCOVERED intent will be sent. Furthermore, the app with the most specific NDEF_DISCOVERED intent filter will be chosen, i.e. an app that also specifies e.g. the MIME type of the NDEF message, e.g. by adding `<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>` to the intent filter, will get all plain text NDEF messages. In general, it is not possible to define an intent filter for NFC that will make sure that your app will always start.

Comment: So we need to use our intent filter based on our tag message format and type of message.There is no common filter for all NFC detection am i right?

Comment: There is no combination of intent filters that will catch all NFC intents. However, in most cases an app is only interested in very specific NFC tags. For example tags with an NDEF message of a specific type or containing a specific URL (or URL prefix).

Answer (score 0):

Check with this for NFC available or not [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008194/how-to-give-condition-to-android-application-to-run-only-on-nfc-enabled-device) and try this for reading tag details [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971820/how-to-read-detected-nfc-tag-ndef-content-details-in-android)..... Add readind tag details code in seperate active..(eg: youractivity) and in manifest give as

`<activity android:name=".youractivity"
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         </intent-filter>
</activity>`