# How to give condition to Android application to run only on NFC enabled device?

Tags: android, nfc

I developing a application which read the NFC Tag details.. In that application i want to give the condition to run only in NFC available devices..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include this in your manifest your app will only be able to run on devices that have NFC:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

`NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)` can also return `null` on a device which has NFC, but the NFC functionality is unavailable for some reason in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're uploading it to the Play Store, then you can choose which devices can download the app, so keep that in mind.

This is how you check to see if the device can use NFC.

```
NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"NFC is not available on this device.", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: ya thanks.... but is there any other option by giving condition in manifest.xml itself?....

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest to require the NFC permission [as specified in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#NFC).

Answer (score 0):

Include this into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
```

Doing so, the Application will only offered for downloading to devices that are capable of using NFC features.

More information about that can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

Comment: if we give like this means the application will run even in NFC not available devices....

Comment: yes, but it is not offered to people at the Play Store. It depends on your distribution strategy if this is sufficient for you or not. This tag is only a semantic one indicating that your application uses NFC.