# How to read from detected NFC tag (NDEF message). Android NFC

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef

Similar question - [How to read detected NFC tag (NDEF content) details in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971820/how-to-read-detected-nfc-tag-ndef-content-details-in-android/9976094#9976094)

I want my android app to be able to read and parse a detected NDEF message.

I have already edited the AndroidManifest.xml to detect nfc tags and I have added the intent filter it looks like this

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

I believe this is fine as when I use the NFCDemo sample app that comes with the SDK to create MockNDEFtags, when the list of applications I can choose to handle these generated tags my app appears.
I then click on my app and it opens up without problem, I just need a way to read the data that was passed to it in the NDEF message. The code:

```
 Tag myTag = (Tag) nfcintent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

 // get NDEF tag details
 Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(myTag);
 ...
 NdefMessage ndefMesg = ndefTag.getCachedNdefMessage();
```

was suggested in a similar question and throughout the web I find many similar answers.
My problem is with the line of code

```
"Tag myTag = (Tag) nfcintent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);"
```

I get the error "nfcintent cannot be resolved"
I realize that the author of the code likely put nfcintent as a placeholder for an intent specific to my app however im not sure what im supposed to put in its place.

My mainactivity that starts my app looks like this

```
public class TabsActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Graph
    TabSpec graphspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Graph");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    graphspec.setIndicator("Graph");
    Intent graphIntent = new Intent(this, GraphActivity.class);
    graphspec.setContent(graphIntent);

    // Tab for Intro
    TabSpec introspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Intro");
    introspec.setIndicator("Intro");
    Intent introIntent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
    introspec.setContent(introIntent);


    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(introspec); // Adding intro tab
    tabHost.addTab(graphspec); // Adding graph tab

}
```

}

I assume as this starts the app it is where the NFC tag must be dealt with. If I can just access the NDEFMessage from the tag I already have the ability to parse it with the NdefMessageParser from the android sample app. I want to parse the information from the NDEFmessage and ultimately have that information accessible by each tab in the app.

Comment: My question is with code snipets such as "Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);" intent cannot be resolved. which intent am I actually supposed to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Snippet to extract message from Tag :

```
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
            .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
    extractMessage(msg);

private void extractMessage(NdefMessage msg) {
        byte[] array = null;
        array = msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload();
}
```

Also Check out this Sample for [NFC Reader/Writer](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/source/browse/Android+NFC/?r=ac94b68476dcb88a4c43a6a62213657ca0bd202a#Android%20NFC/src/com/antares/nfc/client)

Answer (score 2):

To get the intent that passes the NFC tag to start the activity in my case "nfcintent" just use

```
Intent nfcintent = getIntent();
```