# Read ID from NFC in Android

Tags: android, tags, nfc

How do you read an ID from a NFC tag in Android?

Comment: Complete some "hello world" tutorials first, then head over to developer.android.com.  You should know how to build and debug an Android app first.  It will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: As I come from another language(C#) I understand some of it but i'd really like to start with nfc. Thanks.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/reading-nfc-tags-with-android/

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want:

```
byte[] tagId = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
NdefMessage[] msgs = (NdefMessage[]) intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
```

And then you have to parse from byte to String.

```
String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray) 
    {
    int i, j, in;
    String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    String out= "";

    for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) 
        {
        in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the thread: [How to read from detected NFC tag (NDEF message). Android NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698100/how-to-read-from-detected-nfc-tag-ndef-message-android-nfc?rq=1).
It may be helpful to get an idea by first searching for a NFC basic tutorial.

Comment: Thankyou but i dont really want to start by reading the tag itself but only the ID, it shouldnt be that hard, is it?

Comment: Dis my answer below helped?