# how to recognise mifare classic and mifare ultralight when tag is discovered in Android

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I am working on nfc in android and I want to know whether the tag is discovered is Mifare Classic or Mifare Ultralight or any other. plz tell me How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] techs = tag.getTechList();
for (String t : techs) {
  if ("com.android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic".equals(t)) {
    ... // it's MIFARE Classic
  }
  else if ("com.android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight".equals(t)) {
    ... // it's MIFARE Ultralight
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971820/how-to-read-detected-nfc-tag-ndef-content-details-in-android) SO post contains some code with the snippet of

```
String type = ndefTag.getType();         // tag type
```

Which looks like what you need

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still wondering,

```
public synchronized void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
  tag.hasTech(8) // Classic    
  tag.hasTech(9) // Ultralight
```